# UDP dial falied: address already used

Tags: go, networking, udp

I'm writing a program to fetch a udp server. When i first fetch the server it works.

But when i input the program second time. This gives me this error

```
panic: Listen failed:dial udp :8829->:9781: bind: address already in use
```

Code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    log.SetFlags(log.Lshortfile)
    udpServer, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", ":9781")

    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprint("ResolveUDPAddr failed:", err.Error()))
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    client, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", ":8829")
    if err != nil {
            panic(err)
    }

    for {
        fmt.Printf(">> ")

        var input string
        fmt.Scanf("%s", &input)

        conn, err := net.DialUDP("udp", client, udpServer)
        if err != nil {
            panic(fmt.Sprint("Listen failed:", err.Error()))
            os.Exit(1)
        }

        _, err = conn.Write([]byte(input))
        if err != nil {
            panic(fmt.Sprint("Write data failed:", err.Error()))
            os.Exit(1)
        }

        received := make([]byte, 1024)
        _, err = conn.Read(received)
        if err != nil {
            panic(fmt.Sprint("Read data failed:", err.Error()))
            os.Exit(1)
        }

        fmt.Printf("Response: %s\n", string(received))
    }

}
```

I think this happens because i'm using the client twice.

But why this causes "address already in use"

I'm not re-creating the client.

**Solutions I Tried**

One of the solution could be set client as nil.

Setting to nil will generate a random port.

But in my case i need fixed port and fixed network address.

So that would not be the solution.

Comment: `But in my case i need fixed port and fixed network address.` Why?

Comment: *"But when i input the program second time. "* - what do you mean with this: run the same program again in parallel to an existing instance or run it after the previous program has exited?

Comment: You are recreating the connection every loop. Create a single connection and reuse it

Comment: @tkausl Because my server tracks the clients address

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I mean when i fetch the server second time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create the connection before the loop:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    log.SetFlags(log.Lshortfile)
    udpServer, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", ":9781")

    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprint("ResolveUDPAddr failed:", err.Error()))
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    client, err := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", ":8829")
    if err != nil {
            panic(err)
    }

    conn, err := net.DialUDP("udp", client, udpServer)
    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprint("Listen failed:", err.Error()))
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    for {
        fmt.Printf(">> ")

        var input string
        fmt.Scanf("%s", &input)

        _, err = conn.Write([]byte(input))
        if err != nil {
            panic(fmt.Sprint("Write data failed:", err.Error()))
            os.Exit(1)
        }

        received := make([]byte, 1024)
        _, err = conn.Read(received)
        if err != nil {
            panic(fmt.Sprint("Read data failed:", err.Error()))
            os.Exit(1)
        }

        fmt.Printf("Response: %s\n", string(received))
    }

}
```